# How to ignore missing values and NAs in loop in R?

Tags: r, try-catch, lapply, na

I built a quite long script to iterate through a list of CSV files and do some functions (like lm() functions) for each CSV file and I subsequently want to safe the results as a new column in the CSV file in each round.

The problem now is, that there are NA values, and wherever these are, the CSV file should be skipped.
Now I read that `tryCatch` can be used. And I tried a lot around to make it work but I'm missing out something. I get this error: `Error in tryCatch({ : object 'slope_CC' not found`

Can you put several functions inside one tryCatch function?
I'm also confused with how I call the whole thing since first, the code runs for one CSV file and then it should run for the list of CSV files in `file_paths`. But is this done by the lapply function at the end of the script? `slope_list <- lapply(file_paths, NDVI_CC)`

I left out what is not necessary.

This is the code:

```
setwd("E:/PYTHON_ST/breakCSV_PYTHON/AIM_2_regions/Test")
csv_path <- "E:\\PYTHON_ST\\breakCSV_PYTHON\\AIM_2_regions\\Test\\selected0.csv"

NDVI_CC <- function(csv_path) {  
  
  df <- read.csv(csv_path, header = TRUE)

  ...  (some data splitting and selecting)
  
  #a) use tryCatch to continue when errors occur
  slope_CC <- tryCatch({
    
  #b) do mutlipe linear regression  
  model <- lm(NDVI ~ T + Prec + soilM, data = BeforeConf)
  #c) use coefficients of MLR in new fomular to calc. new NDVI values
  NDVI_AfterConf_Climate <- summary(model)$coefficients[1,1] + ((summary(model)$coefficients[2,1])*AfterConf$T) +  ((summary(model)$coefficients[3,1])*AfterConf$Prec) + ((summary(model)$coefficients[4,1])*AfterConf$soilM)
  #d) create new table and put years and old and new NDVI values in it
  Afterconf_update <- cbind(AfterConf$NDVI_Year, AfterConf$NDVI, NDVI_AfterConf_Climate)
  
  #d) Calculate NDVi slopes for climate control
  # x = years (after conf)
  # y = NDVI_AfterConf_Climate
  lm_func_CC <- lm(AfterConf$NDVI_Year ~ Afterconf_update[ ,3]) # select the 6th column -> NDVI_AfterConf_Climate should be added as a column in step before
  # Get coefficient:
  tmp_coef <- coef(lm_func_CC)
  # Store coefficient:
  slope_CC <- tmp_coef[2]   

  
  #e) Calculate NDVi slopes for normal NDVI
  # x = years (after conf)
  # y = NDVI_AfterConf
  lm_func_old <- lm(AfterConf$NDVI_Year ~ Afterconf_update[ ,2]) # select the 6th column -> NDVI_AfterConf_Climate should be added as a column in step before
  # Get coefficient:
  tmp_coef <- coef(lm_func_old)
  # Store coefficient:
  slope_old <- tmp_coef[2]  
  
    },
    error = function(e){ 

      print(e)
      return(NA)
    },
    warning = function(w){

      print(w)
      return(Warn)
    },
  return(slope_CC)
  )
#return(data_frame(cbind(slope_CC)))
#return(data_frame(cbind(slope_old)))
}
Slopes_CC <- lapply(csv_path, NDVI_CC)
mypath <- "E:\\PYTHON_ST\\breakCSV_PYTHON\\AIM_2_regions\\Test"
file_paths <- list.files(pattern=".csv", path=mypath)

# LIST RETURN
slope_list <- lapply(file_paths, NDVI_CC)
```

Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: if there are any NAs in the entire csv? `if (anyNA(df)) return(something)`

Comment: I know from a previous version of the script where I used tryCatch on the first formula that there are NA values. But I need the script to ignore these